# By what mechanism does Internet Explorer send client authetcation information to ADFS in a SSO scenario

Tags: internet-explorer, single-sign-on, adfs

I am trying to understand what is the mechanism which enables the user authentication details to be sent to ADFS server via Internet Explorer.

I am planning to use a cloud based service which is integrated with a local ADFS server.
When a user who is already authenticated through local Active directory tries accessing the Cloud based service through browser he will be redirected to the local ADFS server for authentication.

I understand that as the user is already authenticated via local Active directory, ADFS will not prompt the user for password instead it will automatically authenticate him.

I am trying to understand how user authentication information is passed form the user machine to the ADFS server by the browser. Is it by some function call through jscript,etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADFS is configured with Windows Integrated Authentication. If the user is on the domain, he/she will authenticates with ADFS just like if it was another app on the intranet configured with Windows Integrated Auth (through Kerberos/NTLM). If the user is not on the domain, instead ADFS will show a form where you enter user/password. For this you have to deploy the ADFS Proxy.

Comment: Windows Integrated Authentication does not work with HTTP proxy connection. in that case will it create an issue when a user is connecting to ADFS/ADFS proxy server from internet?